# texmaker doesn't update figure

Tags: floats, texmaker, update

I've changed a figure in my document, but it doesn't update. If I do any other changes in the document, I don't come across this problem.

I've tried to change the name of the figure and as well the label of the figure,but that didn't work...

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What kind of figure is it? Created? Imported, and if so, what extension?

Comment: Its a png extention

Comment: By "update" I suppose you mean that the PDF doesn't show the different png, but still shows the old one. You can try deleting the auxiliary files, although this will break references and figure placement, so you might have to rerun the compilation a second time to fix those.

Comment: by auxiliar files, you mean .*aux?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to delete them, you can simply move them out of the folder and recompile and see if that works.

Comment: Have you done a new LaTeX run? Does the `log` file of the new run show an error?